# How to Change Class onclick?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

This code works with soundcloud's widget to allow remote text buttons and I am trying to make it work as a remote for one image button that has different pictures pause/play depending on class selected, as opposed to txt_on_pause txt_on_play. Any ideas on how to toggle that?

```
$(function () {
    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
        widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe),
        txt_on_pause = '&iexcl;Escuchar m&uacute;sica!',
        txt_on_play = 'Escuchando algo de m&uacute;sica... (click para pausar)';
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle").html(txt_on_pause);
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle").html(txt_on_pause);
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle").html(txt_on_play);
    });
    $(".sc-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        widget.toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `addClass` and `removeClass` functions should work.

```
$(function () {
    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
        widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe),
        txt_on_pause = '&iexcl;Escuchar m&uacute;sica!',
        txt_on_play = 'Escuchando algo de m&uacute;sica... (click para pausar)';

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle")
            .removeClass('pause')
            .removeClass('play')
            .addClass('ready'));
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle")
            .removeClass('play')
            .removeClass('ready')
            .addClass('pause');
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
        $(".sc-toggle")
            .removeClass('pause')
            .removeClass('ready')
            .addClass('play');
    });
    $(".sc-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        widget.toggle();
    });

});
```